# How do you install and configure customer managed ORDS on Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, rest

Has anyone been able to successfully install and configure Customer Managed ORDS on Autonomous Database? I have been trying to follow the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/19.4/aelig/installing-and-configuring-customer-managed-ords-autonomous-database.html#GUID-D90EFD26-AC36-4907-BF95-3E05E82BC3E0) but can't seem to start ORDS. My customer managed environment for ORDS runs in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (Oracle Linux 8.5). I have followed it up to the step "/opt/oracle/ords start" but then get the error "-bash: /opt/oracle/ords: Is a directory". I also tried to follow this [tutorial](https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/2004/) but when I ran the command "sudo systemctl start ords" I get an error: "Job for ords.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ords.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.". Has anyone been able to successfully set this up and if so, can you provide the link or explain the steps you used to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In my case looking at /var/log/ords/ords.log revealed a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError".

Adding the following line into /etc/ords/ords.conf solved the problem of not being able to start/enable ords using systemctl.

JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024M